# Coordinate calculation problem!

Tags: c#, arrays, math, multidimensional-array

I am using a single-dimensional array to simulate a two-dimensional array, due to the performance increase of doing so.

The formular for finding the index of where to place the item is the following, when the height of the array is 30 items, and the width of the array is 20 items.

offset = x * 30 + y

Given this same information, how would I convert an offset back into positions? I know it's possible. I just can't think of how to do it.

Comment: _due to the performance increase of doing so_...  can you elaborate on this point?  AFAIK, C# will essentially compile to the same type of arithmetic that you describe (only possibly doing this in a more efficient fashion)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int x = offset / 30;
int y = offset % 30;
```

Comment: @Mathias You've switched your definition! According to the question, offset = 30*x + y. So if x:11 and y:3, then offset = 30*(11) + 3 == 333. 333 / 30 == 11, and 333 % 30 == 3.

Answer (score 1):

You can use division and modulo to do so.

I don't know what you're using this for of course, but please consider that readability by far outweighs performance.
Rule of thumb: ONLY optimize if there actually is a speed issue present.

In fact if you **are** worried about performance, then reconsider the spacial locality of your array. If you are to run a loop through all elements then in your case do it by columns, not rows. 
As you have organized your array in that direction.

I would've done it by rows (readability and maintainability in mind):

```
offset = y * 20 + x
```

Comment: I believe you are wrong in terms of performance. I am making a game that must run on really low-spec PCs. It has to be incredibly fast, and must do thousands of these things every second.

Comment: @Mathias Lykkegaard Lorenzen: Stop _believing_ start _asserting_.  Simple timing tests or more sophisticated profiling tools should tell you were the real performance bottleneck reside.  Have you heard about `premature optimization`?